# Fullscreen service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-service, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

I have made a service that puts black rectangle on top of every activity and the screen goes black except status/notification bar and navigation bar. My goal is to hide everything. How can I make this black rectangle go fullscreen? I have tried using `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` and `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN`, but it didn't work. I have read about disabling the TypeGuard, but even that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    ImageView black = new ImageView(this);
    black.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.addView(black);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;

    windowManager.addView(layout, params);
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem, and how?

Answer (score 2):

i solved this issue just simply adding one line

```
layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this program

```
    if (null == mInflater) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }if (mLockscreenView == null) mLockscreenView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_locokscreen, null);

mLockscreenView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            mWindowManager.addView(mLockscreenView, mParams);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            mLockscreenView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLockscreenView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                        }
                    },2000);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not working. View in a service is not drawn over navigation keys and status bar.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
getSupportActionBar().hide();   
mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Where `fullscreen_content` is the parent layout.

Comment: This cannot be applied to Service. `getSupportActionBar()` is a method that can be used in classes that are extending Activity.